# Object tracking in python using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, object, tracking

I'm trying to modify this code to allow tracking of multiple objects of the same color and draw a path where the object travel. Currenlty the code just tracks the largest object based on color and the travel path dissappears as the object moves around the video. Finally, I could use some guidance on how to create a new video file capturing the paths. This is my first post so I'm not sure if the code was posted correctly lol. Go easy on me ;)

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# define the lower and upper boundaries of the "green"
# object in the HSV color space, then initialize the
# list of tracked points
greenLower = (29, 86, 6)
greenUpper = (64, 255, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"])

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

# keep looping
while True:
# grab the current frame
(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()

# if we are viewing a video and we did not grab a frame,
# then we have reached the end of the video
if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
    break

# resize the frame, blur it, and convert it to the HSV
# color space
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
# blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# construct a mask for the color "green", then perform
# a series of dilations and erosions to remove any small
# blobs left in the mask
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

# find contours in the mask and initialize the current
# (x, y) center of the ball
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
center = None

# only proceed if at least one contour was found
if len(cnts) > 0:
    # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
    # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
    # centroid
    c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
    ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

    # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
    if radius > 10:
        # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
        # then update the list of tracked points
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
            (0, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

# update the points queue
pts.appendleft(center)

# loop over the set of tracked points
for i in xrange(1, len(pts)):
    # if either of the tracked points are None, ignore
    # them
    if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
        continue

    # otherwise, compute the thickness of the line and
    # draw the connecting lines
    thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
    cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)

# show the frame to our screen
cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

# if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
if key == ord("q"):
    break

# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if you're new to coding multiple object tracking is maybe a bit advanced (consider problems like overlapping movement). Also Stack Overflow is aimed at precise questions, answers to which are useful for a broader audience. I recommend tackling the easier problems first (like creating the video with the path) and working towards the harder problem later.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do change the code that selects only the largest object of the color, to any object of that color?
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # find the largest contour in the mask, then use
        # it to compute the minimum enclosing circle and
        # centroid
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))